# Create assembly from System.Web in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have following problem:

I need to create an assembly in SQL Server database from `system.web.dll` with following script:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SystemWeb 
FROM 'C:\WINDOWS\MICROSOFT.NET\FRAMEWORK\V2.0.50727\SYSTEM.WEB.DLL' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

At fist cannot create because I retrieve some error because don't find some dependencies dll.

I start to install first the dependencies like system.drawing.dll an so on without problem but when I'm trying to install `system.web.dll` it require `System.EnterpriseServices.dll` that require `System.Runtime.Remoting.dll` that require `System.Web` and here I'm inside a circle and cannot go OUT.

Somebody can help to resolve it?

Windows Server 2008 / SQL Server 2008 Enterprise

Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: Check out [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489748/wcf-client-inside-sql-clr) about deploying assemblies into the SQL CLR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 CLR only supports a limited list of assemblies out of the box (see [this document here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)) - and `system.web` is not part of that list.

If you need to deploy something else, like `system.web` then you need to do so with the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` call.

Here's was a <strike>[step-by-step explanation on how to do it]</strike> - for `system.web`, by the way.

The key statement in that article is:

> `CREATE ASSEMBLY SystemWeb`
>   `from 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll'`
>   `with permission_set = unsafe`
>
> *Since all the dependent assemblies are
>   in the same directory, SQL Server
>   would automatically register them.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thankyou for help this thread I see before and I had interesting situation:

Comment: Beware the 'step-by-step explanantion on how to do it' link above. Seems 'sqldev.org' no longer exists, and the first two times (I got curious after the first one ;-)  ) took me to pages with 'too good to be true' offers. The third time just took me to the sqldev.org site, but it just shows loads of adverts.

Comment: @cyberspy: thanks - removed that dead link - haven't found anything useful just now

Answer (score 1):

These are the assemblies you need to deploy, but do you really want to do this?

```
system.web, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=x86.
system.drawing, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil.
system.directoryservices, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil.
system.directoryservices.protocols, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil.
system.enterpriseservices, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=x86.
system.runtime.remoting, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089, processorarchitecture=msil.
system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil.
system.design, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil.
system.windows.forms, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089, processorarchitecture=msil.
accessibility, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil.
system.drawing.design, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil.
system.web.regularexpressions, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil.
system.serviceprocess, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil.
system.configuration.install, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil.
```