# I cannot use WCF in SQL CLR 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf, clr, sqlclr

When adding my assemblies to SQL Server 2012, dependencies draw in `system.servicemodel` which draws in `microsoft.visualbasic.activities.compiler`, and that bring the following error:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly '<assembly name>' failed because assembly 'microsoft.visualbasic.activities.compiler' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly. 
Unverifiable PE Header/native stub.
```

It seems that WCF DLLs cannot be added to SQL Server 2012.

Is there a workaround? Is this fixed in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Could you just explain to those of us that like a decent architecture why you would ever get the idea to run WCF within a database backend?

Comment: Agree with @TomTom that this seem like a really bad idea. SSIS with a scripting task is an easy way to send data to/from a WCF service.

Comment: I do not actually want to use WCF, but some dependencies draw in system.servicemodel. I wanted to avoid factoring those dependencies out, because it's a rather large project, but that is what we'll probably do. Architecturally it would be cleaner too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SQL-Server only allows a rather limited subset of C#, for security reasons. 
For example, adding a reference to System.Web is sufficient that it doesn't work.

Perhaps you can rip the part of System.ServiceModel that you need out of the mono sourcecode and get it to work that way. With luck, if you need only one or two function calls, so you can get it to work with a few changes.

On a sidenote: If you could add WCF in a CLR-Stored Procedure, you could make SQL-Express use HTTP-Endpoints. But one of the defining limitations of SQL-Server Express is, that the Express version doesn't allow that. If that was possible, you could circumvent that limitation, and Microsoft certainly doesn't want that.

See also this post:
[WCF Client Inside SQL CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489748/wcf-client-inside-sql-clr?rq=1)

Comment: Would you happen to know if this was fixed in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: What fixed? That they allow a totally borked approach that noone with any respect for the database would even try out? Rather not.

Comment: @Oszkar: As I said: No, it's not a bug, and it therefore isn't fixed.